# Laravel 5.4, while returning view that submits a form, i get the error; "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected"

Tags: laravel

Basically I'm trying to integrate a payment gateway to my project, and to do this, I'm building the parameters in my controller and passing it to my view. However while processing the view, I get the error stated above, "Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected".

Controller  Code:

```
public function paymentKiple($user, $order, $cart_total, $discount){
        $domain = session('current_domain');
        $settings = $domain->getConfig();

        $dueDate2 = Carbon::now();
        $dueDate = $dueDate2->toDateString();
        //dd($dueDate->toDateString());
        $ord_mercref = $order['id'];
        $merchantid = \Config::get('constants.KIPLE_MERCHANT_ID_DEV');
        $merchantsecret = \Config::get('constants.KIPLE_MERCHANT_SECRET_DEV');
        $cart_total2 = number_format($cart_total, 2);
        $amtstring = (string)$cart_total2;
        $amount = str_replace('.', '', $amtstring); 
        $key2 = $merchantsecret . $merchantid . $ord_mercref . $amount;
        $key = sha1($key2);
        //dd($key ." " .  $key2 . " " .$cart_total);

        $query = [
            'ord_date' => $dueDate,
            'ord_totalamt' => $cart_total,
            'ord_gstamt' => 0.00,
            'ord_shipname' => $user['name'],
            'ord_mercref' => $ord_mercref,
            'ord_mercID' => $merchantid,
            'ord_returnURL' => 'http://local.site.com/order/status',
            'merchant_hashvalue' => $key
        ];

$query2 = (object)$query;

        return View::make('kiple.kiple')->with('data', $query2);
    }
```

View Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function closethisasap() {
 document.forms["redirectpost"].submit();
  }
 </script>
  </head>
 <body onload="closethisasap();">
 <form name="redirectpost" method="POST" action="https://example.kp.com/uat.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="ord_date" value="{{ $data->ord_date }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="ord_totalamt" value="{{ $data->ord_totalamt }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="ord_gstamt" value="{{ $data->ord_gstamt }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="ord_shipname" value="{{ $data->ord_shipname }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="ord_mercref" value="{{ $data->ord_mercref }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="ord_mercID" value="{{ $data->ord_mercID }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="ord_returnURL" value="{{ $data->ord_returnURL }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="merchant_hashvalue" value="{{ $data->merchant_hashvalue }}">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you do `dd($domain);` and let me see the value it has?

Comment: Basically it returns to me the collection from tbl_domain, that shows what url and environment i'm using.